# Loop through rows DataTable in C# and update variables

Tags: c#, sql, loops, datatable

I am trying to loop over a DataTable in c# and get the values from the cells. The data received back could look something like this depending on the number of months selected.

```
Total   Year    Month   TypeId
466     2018    1       1
77      2018    1       2
471     2018    2       1
58      2018    2       2
459     2018    3       1
151     2018    3       2
```

Month 1 being equal to January. How would I split up this data based on dates entered so if someone is looking for March data I would want to add up the totals for March (459 + 151)

Here is my code at moment.

```
                    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                            {                                    
                                result.Total = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Total"]);

                            }
                        }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be very inefficient. SQL version might be better alternative.

Comment: Are there more than a DataTable in the DataSet? Have you tried dataTable.Select() method to filter the data?

Comment: I agree with @MaciejLos  Issuing a 2nd SQL command to do this simple totally will be more straightforward and quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the rows of all tables, but then you are always using the first row of the first table. This will obviously give you the wrong result. You have to use the value of the current row. If you want to only include the march values, you need to skip all other rows:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {                                    
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row["Month"]) != 3)
            {
                continue;
            }
            result.Total = Convert.ToInt32(row["Total"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that all tables in your dataset have at least a "Month" and a "Total" column. Most real-world datasets do not look like this. Since you do not show us the dataset, I assume that this actually is the underlying structure.

Comment: Ok I understand that I am just getting one value back with Rows[0] so how would I split up the data if I dont know what months the user will select.

Comment: I want to split the data by months and years?

Answer (score 0):

Use below to get sum for march.

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt1.Compute("SUM(Total)", "Month = 3"));
```